# curl: What's the difference between -d and --data-binary options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, curl

I'm trying to send a post request to a REST API. I noticed that everything works fine when I pass parameters with -d option in curl. Example:

```sh
curl "https://mywebsite.com" -d "param1=x" -d "param2=y" -u "3SUHZb0sanKWrQ"
```

However, if a send parameters as a json object and using --data-binary, I receive an error from the Api (as if no parameters were received). Example:

```sh
curl "https://mywebsite.com" --data-binary $'{ "param1": "x", -d "param2":"y" }' -u "3SUHZb0sanKWrQ"
```

I thought the two approaches had the same behavior, but I think I'm wrong. What's the difference between these two approaches?

P.S.: the second request is the curl request that I get when select <kbd>copy as cURL</kbd> option on Google Chrome, because the actual request is a $http.post in Angular with its data payload as a JSON object. What can I do in Angular to get it working?

```js
var data = { 
  "param1": "x", 
  "param2": "y" 
};

$http({
    url: "https://mywebsite.com",
    method: 'POST',
    data: data
}).then(function successCallback(response){
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: -d is just the short for --data. --data-binary is another option.

Comment: From `man curl`:  --data-binary (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.

              If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename.  *Data is posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that newlines and carriage  returns  are
              preserved and conversions are never done.*

              If this option is used several times, the ones following the first will append data as described in -d, --data.

Comment: I think you need to add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`. Otherwise as with `-d`/`--data`, `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is sent. `curl "https://mywebsite.com" --data-binary $'{ "param1": "x", -d "param2":"y" }` without any `-H` option specified is taking what looks like an `application/json` message and causing it to be sent with a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. So the server interprets it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`, and then fails to process it properly because it’s not actually structured as form data.

Comment: `--data-binary` sends the data completely as-is, without stripping newlines or other changes.  `-d`/`--data` strips newlines (and maybe also leading/trailing space) & may do other changes

So despite the name `--data-binary` isn’t just for binary—it’s for cases where you want to ensure the data is posted exactly as-is with, without any changes.  `--data-as-is` would be a better name.

And as mentioned above, both `--data-binary` and `-d`/`--data` send the POST as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` unless you give `-H "Content-Type: …"` to change that.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is what I got with `curl --help`:

```
 -d, --data DATA     HTTP POST data (H)
     --data-raw DATA  HTTP POST data, '@' allowed (H)
     --data-ascii DATA  HTTP POST ASCII data (H)
     --data-binary DATA  HTTP POST binary data (H)
     --data-urlencode DATA  HTTP POST data url encoded (H)
     --delegation STRING  GSS-API delegation permission
     --digest        Use HTTP Digest Authentication (H)
     --disable-eprt  Inhibit using EPRT or LPRT (F)
     --disable-epsv  Inhibit using EPSV (F)
     --dns-servers   DNS server addrs to use: 1.1.1.1;2.2.2.2
     --dns-interface  Interface to use for DNS requests
     --dns-ipv4-addr  IPv4 address to use for DNS requests, dot notation
     --dns-ipv6-addr  IPv6 address to use for DNS requests, dot notation§
```

So, the difference is just that with -d data sent is not binary content.

Comment: Explanations repeating what's written there already don't help.

Answer (score 12):

- `-d @file` or equivalently `--data @file` will send the file but stripping out carriage returns and newlines (and maybe also doing character set conversion)
- `--data-binary @file` will send the file as-is
- `--data-raw @file` will send the literal string "@file"
- Without an initial @-sign all three behave identically, sending the following argument as a literal string.

Moreover all three set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` unless you override it; if you are sending JSON, you probably want to set `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`.

I suggest that if you want to send a literal string from the command line, use `--data-raw`, and if you want to send a file, use `--data-binary @file`.